# How can I auto filter a HTML selectlist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, autosuggest, autofilter

I have a HTML select list with quite a few (1000+) names. I have a javascript in place which will select the first matching name if someone starts typing. This matching looks at the start of the item:

```
var optionsLength = dropdownlist.options.length;
  for (var n=0; n < optionsLength; n++)
  {
    var optionText = dropdownlist.options[n].text;
    if (optionText.indexOf(dropdownlist.keypressBuffer,0) == 0)
    {
      dropdownlist.selectedIndex = n;
      return false; 
    }
  }
```

The customer would like to have a suggest or autofilter: typing part of a name should 'find' all names containing that part. I've seen a few Google Suggest like options, most using Ajax, but I'd like a pure javascript option, since the select list is already loaded anyway. Pointers anyone?

Comment: Then you'd have to pull out elements ?-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this filter script
http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/filterlist/

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (optionText.indexOf(dropdownlist.keypressBuffer,0) == 0)
```

to

```
if (optionText.indexOf(dropdownlist.keypressBuffer) > 0)
```

To find `dropdownlist.keypressBuffer` anywhere in the `optionText`.

Comment: While this will select the first option to contain the key pressed, it fails to filter results based on more then 1 keypress.

Answer (score 2):

I would set up a cache to hold the `options` inside my `select`. And instead of filtering `options` in the `select`, I would clear the `select`, and re-populate it with matched `options`.

Pseudo-code galore:

```
onLoad:
    set cache

onKeyPress:
    clear select-element
    find option-elements in cache
    put found option-elements into select-element
```

Here's a little POC I wrote, doing filtering on `selects` from what is selected in another `select`--in effect chaining a bunch of selects together.

Perhaps it can give you a few ideas:

```
function selectFilter(_maps)
{
    var map = {};


    var i = _maps.length + 1; while (i -= 1)
    {
        map = _maps[i - 1];


        (function (_selectOne, _selectTwo, _property)
        {
            var select = document.getElementById(_selectTwo);
            var options = select.options;
            var option = {};
            var cache = [];
            var output = [];


            var i = options.length + 1; while (i -= 1)
            {
                option = options[i - 1];

                cache.push({
                    text: option.text,
                    value: option.value,
                    property: option.getAttribute(_property)
                });
            }


            document.getElementById(_selectOne).onchange = function ()
            {
                var selectedProperty = this
                                       .options[this.selectedIndex]
                                       .getAttribute(_property);
                var cacheEntry = {};
                var cacheEntryProperty = undefined;


                output = [];

                var i = cache.length + 1; while (i -= 1)
                {
                    cacheEntry = cache[i - 1];

                    cacheEntryProperty = cacheEntry.property;

                    if (cacheEntryProperty === selectedProperty)
                    {
                        output.push("<option value=" + cacheEntry.value + " "
                        _property + "=" + cacheEntryProperty + ">" +
                        cacheEntry.text + "</option>");
                    }
                }

                select.innerHTML = output.join();
            };
        }(map.selectOne, map.selectTwo, map.property));
    }
}


$(function ()
{
    selectFilter([
        {selectOne: "select1", selectTwo: "select2", property: "entityid"},
        {selectOne: "select2", selectTwo: "select3", property: "value"}
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The YUI libraries have a library for this sort of functionality, called [AutoComplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/).

The DataSource for AutoComplete can be local javascript objects, or can be easily switched to Ajax if you change your mind.

The YUI components are pretty customizable with a fair bit of functionality.

Edit: I'm not sure if you can get it to work with a select box as required by the question though.  Might be possible.

Comment: Although I swear by jQuery, this seems like a good solution. A good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176324/why-does-everyone-like-jquery-more-than-prototypescriptaclous-or-mootools-or-wh